# WP7 How to reduce the size of an image

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my app I need to show various images(from server). The images retrieved from server are in different sizes. I want to give a uniform size to all the images(say width - 124, height - 100). I am getting image data as a stream and creating a BitmapImage object by passing the stream to the constructor. After creating the BitmapImage object, I create an Image object and set the BitmapImage object as a source of the image object and then I set the width and height values of the image object. Then I set the Streatch property of the image as "image.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill". But the image is cutting off(either the top portion or the width). Can any one tell me how to reduce the size of an image with out any image cutting off.

Comment: Have you tried put this Image inside StackPanel with width 124 and height 100?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to resize the image and don't care about changing the aspect ratio, set the Stretch property to `Fill`.

See the details on MSDN for the different Stretch options at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch(v=VS.95).aspx.

Comment: Sounds like he might be looking for `Uniform`, but either way +1 for the MSDN link.